# Datetime conversion from string to postgresql datetime using python

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

How do I convert a timezone aware date string from value to save in postgresql datetime and retrieve in local time. What I tried using api:

new_data['mdate'] = request.json.get('mdate')

The `value entered is: 03/27/2018 3:03 PM` 
%m/%d/%YT%H:%Y and the 'AM' / 'PM' string,  If this is edited, while trying to resave it has changed to: 2018-03-29T15:03+14:00.  How to convert the +14 part of this format to local timezone and display back.
The error I get is :

```
> new_data['due_date'].rsplit('+')[0],'%m/%d/%YT%H:%M')   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
>     (data_string, format))
> 
> ValueError: time data '2018-03-29T15:03' does not match format
> '%m/%d/%YT%H:%M'
```

Comment: Why are you using `'%m/%d/%YT%H:%M'` when your date format has `-` between year and month and date? Also year is at first position. Use `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'`.

Comment: @AnkitSeth, you didn't read the question correctly

Comment: I just told the solution for the error you are getting in your code.

Comment: What is the final output for this date you want? I got `'2018-03-29 15:03'`.